# Product of Lebesgue-measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $M_1$ be the Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $M_2$ be the Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $M_1\times M_1\neq M_2$, by considering a set $E\times\{0\}$, where $E\subseteq[0,1]$ and $E\not\in M_1$.

The Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are generated by finite unions of rectangles. If $E\not\in M_1$, then it looks like $E\times\{0\}$ is not in $M_2$, and it is not in $M_1\times M_1$ either. So I'm quite confused.

Comment: $E\times\{0\}$ is a subset of a set of measure zero, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E\times \left\{0\right\}$ is in $M_2$ because it has (outer) measure zero,

since you can cover it by rectangles of the form:

$$[0,1] \times [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$$